How to prevent the automatic insertion of semicolons in VSC
We use a repository in the dev team. This contains a .vscode/settings.json file that defines the necessary settings for our local workspace. We work with Vue and have the Vue extension and the ESLint extension for JavaScript.
The settings look like this:
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
  },
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint"
  },
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "stylelint.vscode-stylelint"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  },
  "volar.preview.port": 3000,
  "volar.completion.preferredTagNameCase": "pascal",
  "eslint.options": {},
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit",
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": "explicit",
    "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "stylelint.packageManager": "pnpm",
  "stylelint.validate": [
    "css",
    "scss",
    "vue"
  ],
  "cSpell.words": [
    "Composables",
    "Customizer",
    "destr",
    "flagpack",
    "Iconify",
    "ofetch",
    "psudo",
    "stylelint",
    "touchless",
    "triggerer",
    "vuetify",
    "nuxt"
  ],
  "commentAnchors.tags.anchors": {
    "ℹ️": {
      "scope": "hidden",
      "highlightColor": "#3498DB",
      "styleComment": true,
      "isItalic": false
    },
    "": {
      "scope": "file",
      "highlightColor": "#98C379",
      "styleComment": true,
      "isItalic": false
    },
    "❗": {
      "scope": "hidden",
      "highlightColor": "#FF2D00",
      "styleComment": true,
      "isItalic": false
    }
  },
  "highlight.regexFlags": "gi",
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(100vh|translate|margin:|padding:|margin-left|margin-right|rotate|text-align|border-top|border-right|border-bottom|border-left|float|background-position|transform|width|height|top|left|bottom|right|float|clear|(p|m)(l|r)-|border-(start|end)-(start|end)-radius)": [
      {
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderColor": "tomato",
        "borderStyle": "solid"
      }
    ],
    "(overflow-x:|overflow-y:)": [
      {
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderColor": "green",
        "borderStyle": "solid"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
}

When the vue file is saved, ESLint removes the semicolons for imports and the Vue extension adds them again. However, the semicolons should not be added.
I can hardly change the defaultFormatter for Vue files because we all share this file and the other developers do not have this problem.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? I have already deleted all extensions and downloaded the necessary extensions. Was not successful

"javascript.format.semicolons": "ignore",


It didn't help. Do you maybe need more information?

install prettier plugin  and  add "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {"prettier": {"semi": false }}
